Simple but complex - Nonodoku
I'm back with more Nonodokus. This one is special because it combines the rules of a Jigsaw Sudoku with colored sections. The rules are simple: place the numbers 1 to 9 in each box or colored section without repeating any of them.
The numbers next to each row and column, like in a Nonogram, show you the order of the numbers, but they don’t have to be next to each other. For example, if you see a 5-3 in the first row, it means the 5 comes before the 3, but they don’t necessarily have to be side by side.
¡I hope you enjoy this new challenge!


Nice puzzle! Here's the solution:

 


Step by step:
1.

Starting off with the 3s, there is only one place for a 3 in the green section. From the clues, we know 2 has to be after 4 in the 7th row. As a 2 has to be on the left of 4 in the 6th row, and the 2 in the 7th row already, there is only one place for a 2 in the green area.

Furthermore, in the 8th row - there is only one place for a 4 as it can't be in the middle row as that leaves no space for the 5 and 9, so it must be in column 1. This also means the 8 in column 1 is at the bottom, as it can't be above due to the row clues.







In the purple box, the top row must contain the 2, but it must be left of the 4 so can be placed. This now means there is only one place for a 2 on the bottom row. In the middle row, there is only one spot for an 8, as it needs to leave space on the right for a 2, and the second column means it cant be above the 2 there, so it must be in the 3rd column. This also means the 2 must be right next to it:



3:

The 3 must be above the 8 in the 3rd column, and there is now only one place for a 3 in the second row - at the start.

There must be a 2 in the 3rd column blue cells, so those cells can't contain 1-9 for the clue, as that would leave no space for a 2. Hence the 1 is at the top.

All the 3s can now be filled in, starting with the top right cell.



4:

In the second column, the 9 must be at the bottom due to the row clues. This means a 7 can be placed next to it in the final row. The box bottom left can have a 1 filled.

There is now a 1/5 pair in the bottom right of the bottom row, placing a 4 and a 6 to the left of it. The bottom right box now only has one place for an 8.

The bottom row can now be completed, as 5 must be above 4 in column 8:



5:

Column 6 means a 1 must be in either row 4 or 6 in that column. But that means as they're in the same box there is only one place for a 1 in the green area - C6R6.

In the 3rd row, there is only one place for a 1, and the remaining two 1s can also be placed.

In the 7th column, the green area cell must now be a 5. This also completes the bottom left box. A 5 can also be placed in the 3rd row.



6:

In the 9th column, 6 can only be placed in one cell, which also places an 8 right below it.

The purple area has only one place for an 8, leaving one place for a 5 next to it. There is also only one place for a 6 in this area.

The middle area has one place for an 8, placing a 4 from that rows clue on the right of it.

The 8th column has one place for an 8.



7:

There is only one place for a 5 in the 6th column, and the top of the 7th must be 9. The 4/7 pair beneath it means the orange cell in column 6 is a 9, which solves column 6. The bottom 4 rows can now all be filled, as well as the final column.



8:

The middle row can now be completed, followed by the middle and right box.

The 7th column then solves, and a 5 placed in the 4th row. The 4th row then solves.

This solves the orange area, and then the middle column. The 1st column then solves, then the top row, and then finally the blue area - solving the puzzle!



